# How do I configure Mediawiki on EC2 if anonymous browsing is disabled?

Tags: server, software-installation, amazon-ec2, mediawiki

So I have new MediaWiki instance install on a brand new Amazon EC2 instances. All is going swimmingly, until I have to log in via the web browser to configure it. Since I'm running on a hosted server, I can't hit `http://localhost/mediawiki/config/index.php` like [the instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/mediawiki.html%20the%20instructions) say to.

If I try to hit it via `http://<My IP address>/mediawiki/config/index.php`, my browser just tries to download the file because anonymous browsing isn't enabled. I seem to be before LocalSettings.php is created, so I don't know how to move forward from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is a splendid generic way of accessing remote resources as if they were local.

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 username@EC2machine
```

this will tunnel the port 80 (the http protocol) , on your EC2 instance to your own computers loopback interface on the port 8080

Simply typing `http://localhost:8080` on your computers web browser will redirect the request to your EC2 instance through the created SSH tunnel

the reason i choose 8080 instead of 80 for the loopback interface port, is that ports below 1024 are privileged and require sudo to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a [juju charm for mediawiki](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/mediawiki), though it is meant for higher scale installations which would have multiple web-heads and dedicated instances for MySQL, memcached, etc. To use it you can install and setup juju (see https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/) and then type

```
 juju bootstrap
 juju deploy mediawiki mywiki
 juju deploy mysql wiki-db
 juju add-relation wiki-db mywiki
 juju expose mywiki
```

This will run *three* EC2 instances (1 juju server, 1 mediawiki, 1 mysql). You can run it on one as well if you add '`placement: local`' to your environments.yaml, but that is an undocumented hack that may be removed.

This should result in a running, working mediawiki at the address of the mediawiki server (visible by typing `juju status mywiki`). If you also add memcached, it will scale out pretty heavily with `juju add-unit mywiki`.